# Wordpress has a trash for users? (Wrong result for count_user, greater than expected)

Tags: users, trash

I am using count_users() function to count users on my wordpress sites. In my administration area -> 'Users' I can see 7 users, but the function returns 9. After some time, searching for errors in my code, I noticed that in the admin area there are 7 users listed, but near the 'All' link there is a number counting users and the number is effectively 9.

So, what is happening? Maybe there is a trash for users, and Wordpress is still counting deleted user or something like that?

EDIT: Just for the sake of completeness, tried to delete an user and the total counter is correctly lowered by one unity. Still having two phantom users...

Comment: Do you have PHPMyAdmin or sth. like that? How many entries are there in your `_users` table?

Comment: 7,  so the db is ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the user system does not have a trash (this is the default, obviously you can add pretty anything).

My problem was caused by users meta... If you take a look at the the function count_users (located in wp-includes/user.php), you'll see some comments there. It says that the function:

- Assumes there are neither duplicated nor orphaned capabilities meta_values.
- Assumes role names are unique phrases.

In my case, there were orphan meta values. Deleting from wp_usermeta values having a user_id not present in wp_users table solved the problem.

Delete can be performed with a mysql query like this

```
DELETE FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM wp_users
    WHERE wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
)
```

Comment: Beware: Ran this query in a dev site, it delete my admin user now can't do much.